# Firebase data retrive from database only in login activity when i try to access the current user in any other activity it gives null

Tags: android, firebase

i am trying to develop a chat app using firebase in  login activity if try to get data from firebase database it give me the data

but on any other activity it gives me null on getcurrentuser()

```
    public void  login()
{
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SiginActivity.this,"fail",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        if (user != null) {
                            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
                            String name = user.getDisplayName();
                            String email = user.getEmail();
                            Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

                            // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
                            // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
                            // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
                            String UID = user.getUid();




                        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(UID);
                            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.name ).getValue().toString();
                                    dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.bloodgroup ).getValue().toString();
                                    dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.last_donationdata ).getValue().toString();
                                    dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.last_recieve_blood ).getValue().toString();
                                    dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.lat ).getValue().toString();
                                    dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.lng).getValue().toString();
                                    dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.special_case ).getValue().toString();
                                    dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.image ).getValue().toString();
                                    dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.thumbnail ).getValue().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(SiginActivity.this, dataSnapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });



                        }
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
```

setting activity code

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

     // here it comes null in mCurrentUser
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


    String uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.name ).getValue().toString();
             dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.bloodgroup ).getValue().toString();
             dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.last_donationdata ).getValue().toString();
             dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.last_recieve_blood ).getValue().toString();
             dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.lat ).getValue().toString();
             dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.lng).getValue().toString();
             dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.special_case ).getValue().toString();
             dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.image ).getValue().toString();
             dataSnapshot.child(FDBKeys.thumbnail ).getValue().toString();
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, dataSnapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

tried alot of answer from stack but could not be able to solve the problem anyone can help me i will be very  thankfull

Comment: where are you calling login() ? or where are you using it ?, if you come from login activity logged in, with just an authlistener you can verify if the user is still logged in, also in your other activity you should call mAuth again to get user info and reference to the database (if you are using uid for each one )

Comment: in the login activity login button is calling when click on login button

Comment: and then the user is logged in and when you go to the other activity mAuth == null ?

Comment: did you enabled firebases authentication from firebase console in your project ?

Comment: when i am in login activity then the user logged in every database work or any firebase work perform properly but when i move to anyother activity current user is null

Comment: yes i have enable it

Comment: can you post the code from the activity you are getting the user null ?

Comment: i have mention the code of second activity where i am getting null

Comment: below the line setting activity code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by analyzing your code nothing is in problem  nor in the login code and nor in the data retriving cdoe the only problem will be that you may call FirebaseAuth.getInstance.SignOut(); somewhere accidently in the code analyze your code and remove that , same case i face in firebase integration